# duplicate select rows even distnict

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

i have three tables with inner join when i make select it return duplicate rows i use distict and still return duplicate rows

```
TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Comment](
[Comid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[bookid] [int] NULL,
[U_ID] [int] NULL,
[Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Com_date] [datetime] NULL,
[puplished] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Comment] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

the second table is

```
TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_Reply](
[replyid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Comid] [int] NULL,
[U_ID] [int] NULL,
[replymsg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[rep_datetime] [datetime] NULL,
[is_deleted] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbl_Reply] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

my last one is

```
TABLE [dbo].[Tbl_adminreply](
[adrep_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Comid] [int] NULL,
[adminreply] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Tbi_adminreply] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

tables Reply and Tbl_adminreply have join with comment table with comid 
when i make select it return duplicate rows ?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  Tbl_Comment.Comment, Tbl_Reply.replymsg,   Tbl_Reply.rep_datetime, Tbl_adminreply.adminreply
FROM Tbl_adminreply 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Comment ON Tbl_adminreply.Comid = Tbl_Comment.Comid 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Reply ON Tbl_Comment.Comid = Tbl_Reply.Comid  
WHERE (Tbl_Comment.Comid = 3) ORDER BY Tbl_Reply.rep_datetime DESC
```

Comment: If you use select distinct A,B,C from query. The disinct clause means to select distinct tuples of A, B, and C. I bet your query works exactly this way. If you don't like this answer, you need to show what you got vs. what you want and describe what makes the distinction in you mind that is not being selected as you want.

Comment: What distinct rows you want back? Last entered row?? very first row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
SELECT A.Comment
      ,A.replymsg
      ,A.rep_datetime
      ,A.adminreply
FROM (
        SELECT    Tbl_Comment.Comment
                , Tbl_Reply.replymsg
                , Tbl_Reply.rep_datetime
                , Tbl_adminreply.adminreply
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tbl_Comment.Comid ORDER BY Tbl_Reply.rep_datetime DESC) rn
        FROM Tbl_adminreply 
        INNER JOIN Tbl_Comment    ON Tbl_adminreply.Comid = Tbl_Comment.Comid 
        INNER JOIN Tbl_Reply      ON Tbl_Comment.Comid    = Tbl_Reply.Comid  
        WHERE      Tbl_Comment.Comid = 3 
      ) A
WHERE A.rn = 1
ORDER BY A.rep_datetime DESC
```

Comment: thankx it works but return only one repley even i have more than 2

Answer (score 0):

If it is MS-SQL Server

Please use row_Number() check refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx

let us know if it works

```
WITH Result AS
(
 SELECT c.Comment, r.replymsg,   r.rep_datetime, a.adminreply,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY a.Comid ORDER BY a.Comid, r.rep_datetime) AS ROW_NO
    FROM Tbl_adminreply a
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Comment c ON a.Comid = c.Comid 
    INNER JOIN Tbl_Reply r ON c.Comid = r.Comid  
    WHERE c.Comid = 3
 )

 SELECT Comment, replymsg, rep_datetime, adminreply
 FROM Result where Result.ROW_NO > 2;
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "Tbl_Reply.rep_datetime" could not be bound

Comment: WITH Result AS
(
SELECT Tbl_Comment.Ar_Comment, r.Ar_replymsg,r.rep_datetime, a.Ar_adminreply,
 ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY a.Comid ORDER BY a.Comid, r.rep_datetime) AS ROW_NO
FROM Tbl_adminreply a
INNER JOIN Tbl_Comment ON a.Comid = Tbl_Comment.Comid 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Reply r ON Tbl_Comment.Comid = r.Comid  
WHERE Tbl_Comment.Comid = 3
)

SELECT * FROM Result where Result.ROW_NO >1; --Filtering out all the duplicates FROM Result where Result.ROW_NO > 2; --Filtering out all the duplicates   but some rows duplicte the result get like (1-2-2-3) other time (1-1-2-3) and so on

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more on 2nd point or post query result. 
For the 1 point here is the updated query 
    `WITH Result AS
    (
 SELECT c.Comment, r.replymsg,   r.rep_datetime,a.adminreply,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY a.Comid ORDER BY a.Comid,         r.rep_datetime) AS ROW_NO
 FROM Tbl_adminreply a
 INNER JOIN Tbl_Comment c ON a.Comid = c.Comid 
 INNER JOIN Tbl_Reply r ON c.Comid = r.Comid  
 WHERE c.Comid = 3
      )

      SELECT Comment, replymsg, rep_datetime, adminreply
  FROM Result where Result.ROW_NO > 2;`

Comment: Can you please post the result set or use this: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to set up... may be then I can check on it.

Comment: in another way i have posts every post have many comments each comment have reply from users and admin can also add reply for each erply what is the best way to be done in sql ? which table and relation can be achived